# How i can connect to IKEv2 vpn server on server Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, server, bash, vpn, ipsec

Now I use the **charon-cmd** utility for these purposes like this:

```bash
sudo charon-cmd --host host.domain --identity host.domain --profile ikev2-eap --eap-identity my-identity
```

But maybe there are some other standard solutions? Also, charon-cmd requires you to enter the password for EAP access manually every time, and this is very uncomfortable

Comment: I'm an idiot, disregard the charon comment (I need more coffee xD).  But I will make a note that I don't believe that there is a mechanism in `charon-cmd` to pass password in unless you're using only auth certs, etc.  If you aren't using cert auth - and it seems like you aren't - you don't have a way to pass in the password.  The other way to do this would be to use something like `nmcli` and configure things with the Network Manager command line tools, however that won't work if you are not using Network Manager to manage your server's networking.

Comment: Why use `charon-cmd` on the command line and not configure the `charon` or `charon-systemd` IKE daemon and let it connect automatically in the background?

Comment: @ecdsa Thanks for response, i think i need to try this